# docker-compose up -d send disconnect: Broken pipe

Tags: docker-compose

При очередном запуске(условно на 15 раз) docker-compose up -d **обрывается связь с сервером**

сам файл docker-compose.yml

```
services:

  postgresql:
    container_name: postgresql
    image: bitnami/postgresql:11.11.0
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1024M
        reservations:
          memory: 512M
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=Passw0rd123
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/dumps:/backups
      - ./postgres/dump-restore:/scripts
      - data-postgresql:/bitnami/postgresql
volumes:
  data-postgresql:
    driver: local
```

пытается запустится и обрывает связь
[image: broken pipe]

Перезагрузка сервера не помогла.
Сервер пингуется, на нем работают другие контейнеры, но зайти на него я не могу по ssh.
Я думаю что docker внес изменения в iptables и теперь я немогу подключится к серверу.

И это уже второй сервер за неделю.

Comment: текстовый контент, лучше вставлять как текст, а не картинки

Comment: поправил текст.